In Excel VBA, extract a single txt file from a zip and record txt file name
I receive Zip files containing a single txt of the form "xxxx_Results.txt"
In Excel VBA, I need to extract the txt file and record the txt file name for later manipulation.
I can do the extraction but cannot record the name.
Can anyone help?
